# Converting XML to JSON using GSON in PI Java Mapping

Tags: json, gson, sap-pi, sap-xi

I am facing issue while converting the source XML into JSON using the GSON library. Please find below the source XML, code, actual output and expected output. I am implementing this in Java mapping of SAP PI where I am getting source XML as input to this Java code.

Source XML:

```
<data>
<ERP>0080001</ERP>
<Shiptoparty>0088000</Shiptoparty>
<Shippingpoint>503</Shippingpoint>
<Issuedate>20181102</Issuedate>
<products>
<Unit>L</Unit>
<QTY>2.000 </QTY>
<SKUno>000000000011</SKUno>
</products>
<products>
<Unit>L</Unit>
<QTY>0.000 </QTY>
<SKUno>000000000011000078</SKUno>
</products>
</data>
```

Code:

```
package xmlgsonjson;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.AbstractTransformation;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.StreamTransformationException;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationInput;
import com.sap.aii.mapping.api.TransformationOutput;

public class MakeItJSONByGSON extends AbstractTransformation 
{

public String targetfile ="";

public MakeItJSONByGSON() {}

public void transform(TransformationInput in, TransformationOutput out) throws StreamTransformationException
{
try {
    String sourcexml = "";
    
    String line = "";

    
    InputStream inputstream = in.getInputPayload().getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));
    OutputStream outputstream = out.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream();
   
    byte[] b = null;
    try {
        b = new byte[inputstream.available()];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        inputstream.read(b);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String inputContent = new String(b);
 
    
    
    
    sourcexml = inputContent;



    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            
        sourcexml = sourcexml + line;
    
        
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    
    String jsonPrettyPrintString = gson.toJson(sourcexml);
     
 
    targetfile = jsonPrettyPrintString;
    

out.getOutputPayload().getOutputStream().write(targetfile.getBytes());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Output:

```
"\u003cdata\u003e\n    \u003cERP\u003e0080001\u003c/ERP\u003e\n    \u003cShiptoparty\u003e0088000\u003c/Shiptoparty\u003e\n    \u003cShippingpoint\u003e503\u003c/Shippingpoint\u003e\n    \u003cIssuedate\u003e20181102\u003c/Issuedate\u003e\n    \u003cproducts\u003e\n    \u003cUnit\u003eL\u003c/Unit\u003e\n    \u003cQTY\u003e2.000 \u003c/QTY\u003e\n    \u003cSKUno\u003e000000000011\u003c/SKUno\u003e\n    \u003c/products\u003e\n    \u003cproducts\u003e\n    \u003cUnit\u003eL\u003c/Unit\u003e\n    \u003cQTY\u003e0.000 \u003c/QTY\u003e\n    \u003cSKUno\u003e000000000011000078\u003c/SKUno\u003e\n    \u003c/products\u003e\n    \u003c/data\u003e"
```

Expected output:

```
{"data": [
    {
        "ERP": 0080001,
        "Issuedate": 20181102,
        "Shippingpoint": 503,
        "Shiptoparty": 0088000,
        "products": [
            {
                "Unit": "L"
                "QTY": 2.000,
                "SKUno": 000000000011,   
            },
            {
                "Unit": "L"
                "QTY": 0.000,
                "SKUno": 000000000011000078,
                
            }
        ]
    }
    
]}
```

Kindly let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: `\u003c` corresponds to `<` and `\u003e` corresponds to `>`. Thus the output is `<data><ERP>0080001</ERP>...</products></data>`, same as input string. So, I would say that it didn't recognize an XML object, just a string, and so converted it into a string (so almost nothing). You must use an XML parser.

Comment: Sandra, so you are suggesting me to convert the sourcexml String into xml using XML Parser and then pass that xml to gson.toJson ... right?

Comment: But after parsing , it will not allow me to use XML Document object with JsonObject while conversion.

Comment: Why not use PI / PO built in REST Adapter? No Java mapping neccessary. Available since PO 7.5 SP x (don't know from top of my head)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with encoding. Possible solution is

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(objectToEncode);
byte[] utf8JsonString = jsonString.getBytes("UTF8");
responseToClient.write(utf8JsonString, 0, utf8JsonString.Length);
```

I hope this will work for you :)

Comment: I tried your suggested solution but it didn't worked. It gave me similar output. I want JSON as  output. Please see the expected output which i have posted above.

Comment: I already saw the expected output and I notice that: \u003c **data**\u003e\n \u003c **ERP so in the output you have expected String, but you have extra characters which looks like there is something with encoding.

Comment: Previously I converted the xml to json successfully using JSON instead of GSON, but the values in the array gets rearranged in previous try. JSON moves the insertion order. I want to preserve the order.

Comment: Can you use different library than Gson? I suggest you to use Jackson https://www.baeldung.com/jackson

Comment: is it not possible by using my above code? any changes in the above code will it give me desired output?

Comment: sourcexml = inputContent.getBytes("UTF-8"); can you try this ?

Comment: It's not converting the xml to JSON structure. I have never used GSON before. Just wanted to know whether i am missing anything in code that is needed for this conversion.